# How to use weights in multivariate linear regression in R with lm?

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-testing

I've got a linear regression that looks like:

multivariateModel = lm(cbind(y1, y2, y3)~., data=temperature)

I need to do two things with this, which I've found difficult to do. First is to extract the variances, and right now I'm using sigma(multivariateModel), which has returned

```
  y1       y2       y3
```

31.22918 31.83245 31.01727

I would like to use those 3 sigmas to create variances (sd^2) and weight them against my regression. Currently, weights=cbind(31.22918, 31.83245, 31.01727) is not working, and it's also not working to use matrix 3 columns long with those values repeated.

Here is the dataset in question:

[image]

Is there a way to add these as a weighted matrix so that I can get out a fitted model with this, or is there another package I need to use besides lm for this? Thanks.

Here is a link to the dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zm9pPqOnkBdsPekOf8IoXN8yLr82CCFBuc9EtxN5JII/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your dataset ?

Comment: It has been added.

Comment: Please read carefully the link that I provide you. Right now, your dataset presented as an image is not suitable for copy/paste.

Comment: I added a link to the dataset.